# How do I make my iAd banner appear at bottom of screen?

Tags: objective-c, ios, iad

I have the following code that allows me to position it on the top. I am wanting it to appear at the bottom.

```
 adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
 adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
 adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
 [self.view addSubview:adView];
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Update—@larsacus pointed out this is for 4.2+:

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height;
adView.frame = adFrame;
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

[image: Shown working in simulator]

Comment: Note that this will only work for iOS 4.2+ since `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` and `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape` were both added in 4.2.  Just a heads up.

Comment: @jini Chris didn't answer the question

Comment: This does not move the frame to the bottom of the view. It's still on the top. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Neeku If you post your code in a question I can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

My first answer on SO :)

Why not use the 'center' property of the adView? If the dimensions of your main view are viewWidth and viewHeight:

```
//at the bottom of view,centered
adView.center=CGPointMake(viewWidth/2, viewHeight-adView.frame.size.height);

//at the top, right corner ;)
adView.center=CGPointMake(viewWidth-adView.frame.size.width/2, adView.frame.size.height);
```

Cheers

Comment: I tried something similar but am unsure if Apple will accept forcing the size to something different than the default. Does anyone have experience with uploading an app with a resized iAd banner?

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me move the view to the bottom:

`adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;`

`adView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;`

Comment: This will push the ad view below the screen in many instances. It sounds like your issue more had to do with screen rotation or you're using interface builder and the views were not set up correctly. Are you using a XIB for your view controller?

Comment: Oh! You're right, I noticed there are more than one instances, but I haven't fixed it yet. I don't have any XIBs, this is an old code and I'm updating it. The views are NOT set up correctly at all and it's a mess, and I don't want to spend much time on this. My app comes in one orientation only, so there's no rotation, all I need is to set it to the bottom.I pasted the whole code (of the ads) here, to avoid asking the same question for several times, but I can repost it if needed: http://pastebin.com/k73cyL7R

Comment: Not sure how you recognized that made many instances, but the problem was that I had it in the `loadView` method which called the `createAdView` method before the main view was created. Using a timer the problem is solved.

Comment: using timers is usually a sign you should be doing it a different way. You should create your ad view after your main view and add it as a subview in `viewDidLoad`, not `loadView`. You didn't paste all your code in pastebin (it's missing the method `loadView` where the issue was created) so I wouldn't have been able to diagnose the issue. I'm glad you got it solved, but a timer wouldn't be necessary if you went about it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Using Storyboards, then, ignore that the standard iAd Banner View does not reach the edges of the screen.
Set the iAd banner to be centred, then move it to as close to the bottom as you want. No other width settings (no leading or trailing settings)

Mine looked ok with 8 pixels from the bottom of the superview, but I went with - pixels between the iAd banner and the UIController View.